# Gmail contacts API.3 in php, how to get name and phone from contact?

Tags: php, api, gmail, contacts

i need some advise on this one, im having trouble figuring out the array that comes from google contacts, im already extracting the email from an example i found online, but now i need to extract the name of the contact and the phone number, i am seeing this information in the array doing a print_r() but dont know how to get it.

This is are my files:

gmail.php (this one prints all the emails, here i need also name and phone)

```
include_once 'GmailOath.php';

$oauth =new GmailOath($consumer_key, $consumer_secret, $argarray, $debug, $callback);
$getcontact_access=new GmailGetContacts();

$request_token=$oauth->rfc3986_decode($_GET['oauth_token']);
$request_token_secret=$oauth->rfc3986_decode($_SESSION['oauth_token_secret']);
$oauth_verifier= $oauth->rfc3986_decode($_GET['oauth_verifier']);

$contact_access = $getcontact_access->get_access_token($oauth,$request_token, $request_token_secret,$oauth_verifier, false, true, true);

$access_token=$oauth->rfc3986_decode($contact_access['oauth_token']);
$access_token_secret=$oauth->rfc3986_decode($contact_access['oauth_token_secret']);
$contacts= $getcontact_access->GetContacts($oauth, $access_token, $access_token_secret, false, true,$emails_count);

foreach($contacts as $k => $a)
{
    $final = end($contacts[$k]);
    foreach($final as $email)
    {
            echo 'email: ' . $email["address"] .'<br>';
    }
}
```

GmailOath.php

```
    <?php

    class GmailOath {

        public $oauth_consumer_key;
        public $oauth_consumer_secret;
        public $progname;
        public $debug;
        public $callback;

        function __construct($consumer_key, $consumer_secret, $argarray, $debug, $callback) {
            $this->oauth_consumer_key = $consumer_key;
            $this->oauth_consumer_secret = $consumer_secret;
            $this->progname = $argarray;
            $this->debug = $debug; // Set to 1 for verbose debugging output
            $this->callback = $callback;
        }

        ////////////////// global.php open//////////////
        function logit($msg, $preamble=true) {
            //  date_default_timezone_set('America/Los_Angeles');
            $now = date(DateTime::ISO8601, time());
            error_log(($preamble ? "+++${now}:" : '') . $msg);
        }


        function do_get($url, $port=80, $headers=NULL) {
            $retarr = array();  // Return value
            $curl_opts = array(CURLOPT_URL => $url,
                CURLOPT_PORT => $port,
                CURLOPT_POST => false,
                CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST => false,
                CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER => false,
                CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true);


            if ($headers) {
                $curl_opts[CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER] = $headers;
            }

            $response = $this->do_curl($curl_opts);

            if (!empty($response)) {
                $retarr = $response;
            }

            return $retarr;
        }


        function do_post($url, $postbody, $port=80, $headers=NULL) {
            $retarr = array();  // Return value

            $curl_opts = array(CURLOPT_URL => $url,
                CURLOPT_PORT => $port,
                CURLOPT_POST => true,
                CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST => false,
                CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER => false,
                CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => $postbody,
                CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true);

            if ($headers) {
                $curl_opts[CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER] = $headers;
            }

            $response = do_curl($curl_opts);

            if (!empty($response)) {
                $retarr = $response;
            }

            return $retarr;
        }


        function do_curl($curl_opts) {

            $retarr = array();  // Return value

            if (!$curl_opts) {
                if ($this->debug) {
                    $this->logit("do_curl:ERR:curl_opts is empty");
                }
                return $retarr;
            }


            // Open curl session

            $ch = curl_init();

            if (!$ch) {
                if ($this->debug) {
                    $this->logit("do_curl:ERR:curl_init failed");
                }
                return $retarr;
            }

            // Set curl options that were passed in
            curl_setopt_array($ch, $curl_opts);

            // Ensure that we receive full header
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, true);

            if ($this->debug) {
                curl_setopt($ch, CURLINFO_HEADER_OUT, true);
                curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, true);
            }

            // Send the request and get the response
            ob_start();
            $response = curl_exec($ch);
            $curl_spew = ob_get_contents();
            ob_end_clean();
            if ($this->debug && $curl_spew) {
                $this->logit("do_curl:INFO:curl_spew begin");
                $this->logit($curl_spew, false);
                $this->logit("do_curl:INFO:curl_spew end");
            }

            // Check for errors
            if (curl_errno($ch)) {
                $errno = curl_errno($ch);
                $errmsg = curl_error($ch);
                if ($this->debug) {
                    $this->logit("do_curl:ERR:$errno:$errmsg");
                }
                curl_close($ch);
                unset($ch);
                return $retarr;
            }

            if ($this->debug) {
                $this->logit("do_curl:DBG:header sent begin");
                $header_sent = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HEADER_OUT);
                $this->logit($header_sent, false);
                $this->logit("do_curl:DBG:header sent end");
            }

            // Get information about the transfer
            $info = curl_getinfo($ch);

            // Parse out header and body
            $header_size = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HEADER_SIZE);
            $header = substr($response, 0, $header_size);
            $body = substr($response, $header_size);

            // Close curl session
            curl_close($ch);
            unset($ch);

            if ($this->debug) {
                $this->logit("do_curl:DBG:response received begin");
                if (!empty($response)) {
                    $this->logit($response, false);
                }
                $this->logit("do_curl:DBG:response received end");
            }

            // Set return value
            array_push($retarr, $info, $header, $body);

            return $retarr;
        }


        function json_pretty_print($json, $html_output=false) {
            $spacer = '  ';
            $level = 1;
            $indent = 0; // current indentation level
            $pretty_json = '';
            $in_string = false;

            $len = strlen($json);

            for ($c = 0; $c < $len; $c++) {
                $char = $json[$c];
                switch ($char) {
                    case '{':
                    case '[':
                        if (!$in_string) {
                            $indent += $level;
                            $pretty_json .= $char . "\n" . str_repeat($spacer, $indent);
                        } else {
                            $pretty_json .= $char;
                        }
                        break;
                    case '}':
                    case ']':
                        if (!$in_string) {
                            $indent -= $level;
                            $pretty_json .= "\n" . str_repeat($spacer, $indent) . $char;
                        } else {
                            $pretty_json .= $char;
                        }
                        break;
                    case ',':
                        if (!$in_string) {
                            $pretty_json .= ",\n" . str_repeat($spacer, $indent);
                        } else {
                            $pretty_json .= $char;
                        }
                        break;
                    case ':':
                        if (!$in_string) {
                            $pretty_json .= ": ";
                        } else {
                            $pretty_json .= $char;
                        }
                        break;
                    case '"':
                        if ($c > 0 && $json[$c - 1] != '\\') {
                            $in_string = !$in_string;
                        }
                    default:
                        $pretty_json .= $char;
                        break;
                }
            }

            return ($html_output) ?
                    '<pre>' . htmlentities($pretty_json) . '</pre>' :
                    $pretty_json . "\n";
        }





        function oauth_http_build_query($params, $excludeOauthParams=false) {

            $query_string = '';
            if (!empty($params)) {

                // rfc3986 encode both keys and values
                $keys = $this->rfc3986_encode(array_keys($params));
                $values = $this->rfc3986_encode(array_values($params));
                $params = array_combine($keys, $values);


                uksort($params, 'strcmp');


                $kvpairs = array();
                foreach ($params as $k => $v) {
                    if ($excludeOauthParams && substr($k, 0, 5) == 'oauth') {
                        continue;
                    }
                    if (is_array($v)) {
                        // If two or more parameters share the same name,
                        // they are sorted by their value. OAuth Spec: 9.1.1 (1)
                        natsort($v);
                        foreach ($v as $value_for_same_key) {
                            array_push($kvpairs, ($k . '=' . $value_for_same_key));
                        }
                    } else {
                        // For each parameter, the name is separated from the corresponding
                        // value by an '=' character (ASCII code 61). OAuth Spec: 9.1.1 (2)
                        array_push($kvpairs, ($k . '=' . $v));
                    }
                }

                // Each name-value pair is separated by an '&' character, ASCII code 38.
                // OAuth Spec: 9.1.1 (2)
                $query_string = implode('&', $kvpairs);
            }
            return $query_string;
        }


        function oauth_parse_str($query_string) {
            $query_array = array();

            if (isset($query_string)) {

                // Separate single string into an array of "key=value" strings
                $kvpairs = explode('&', $query_string);

                // Separate each "key=value" string into an array[key] = value
                foreach ($kvpairs as $pair) {
                    list($k, $v) = explode('=', $pair, 2);

                    // Handle the case where multiple values map to the same key
                    // by pulling those values into an array themselves
                    if (isset($query_array[$k])) {
                        // If the existing value is a scalar, turn it into an array
                        if (is_scalar($query_array[$k])) {
                            $query_array[$k] = array($query_array[$k]);
                        }
                        array_push($query_array[$k], $v);
                    } else {
                        $query_array[$k] = $v;
                    }
                }
            }

            return $query_array;
        }


        function build_oauth_header($params, $realm='') {
            $header = 'Authorization: OAuth';
            foreach ($params as $k => $v) {
                if (substr($k, 0, 5) == 'oauth') {
                    $header .= ',' . $this->rfc3986_encode($k) . '="' . $this->rfc3986_encode($v) . '"';
                }
            }
            return $header;
        }


        function oauth_compute_plaintext_sig($consumer_secret, $token_secret) {
            return ($consumer_secret . '&' . $token_secret);
        }


        function oauth_compute_hmac_sig($http_method, $url, $params, $consumer_secret, $token_secret) {

            $base_string = $this->signature_base_string($http_method, $url, $params);
            $signature_key = $this->rfc3986_encode($consumer_secret) . '&' . $this->rfc3986_encode($token_secret);
            $sig = base64_encode(hash_hmac('sha1', $base_string, $signature_key, true));
            if ($this->debug) {
                logit("oauth_compute_hmac_sig:DBG:sig:$sig");
            }
            return $sig;
        }

        /**
         * Make the URL conform to the format scheme://host/path
         * @param string $url
         * @return string the url in the form of scheme://host/path
         */
        function normalize_url($url) {
            $parts = parse_url($url);

            $scheme = $parts['scheme'];
            $host = $parts['host'];
            $port = $parts['port'];
            $path = $parts['path'];

            if (!$port) {
                $port = ($scheme == 'https') ? '443' : '80';
            }
            if (($scheme == 'https' && $port != '443')
                    || ($scheme == 'http' && $port != '80')) {
                $host = "$host:$port";
            }

            return "$scheme://$host$path";
        }

        /**
         * Returns the normalized signature base string of this request
         * @param string $http_method
         * @param string $url
         * @param array $params
         * The base string is defined as the method, the url and the
         * parameters (normalized), each urlencoded and the concated with &.
         * @see http://oauth.net/core/1.0/#rfc.section.A.5.1
         */
        function signature_base_string($http_method, $url, $params) {
            // Decompose and pull query params out of the url
            $query_str = parse_url($url, PHP_URL_QUERY);
            if ($query_str) {
                $parsed_query = $this->oauth_parse_str($query_str);
                // merge params from the url with params array from caller
                $params = array_merge($params, $parsed_query);
            }

            // Remove oauth_signature from params array if present
            if (isset($params['oauth_signature'])) {
                unset($params['oauth_signature']);
            }

            // Create the signature base string. Yes, the $params are double encoded.

            $base_string = $this->rfc3986_encode(strtoupper($http_method)) . '&' .
                    $this->rfc3986_encode($this->normalize_url($url)) . '&' .
                    $this->rfc3986_encode($this->oauth_http_build_query($params));

            $this->logit("signature_base_string:INFO:normalized_base_string:$base_string");

            return $base_string;
        }

        /**
         * Encode input per RFC 3986
         * @param string|array $raw_input
         * @return string|array properly rfc3986 encoded raw_input
         * If an array is passed in, rfc3896 encode all elements of the array.
         * @link http://oauth.net/core/1.0/#encoding_parameters
         */
        function rfc3986_encode($raw_input){

            if (is_array($raw_input)) {
                //return array_map($this->rfc3986_encode, $raw_input);
                return array_map(array($this, 'rfc3986_encode'), $raw_input);

                // return $this->rfc3986_encode($raw_input);
            } else if (is_scalar($raw_input)) {
                return str_replace('%7E', '~', rawurlencode($raw_input));
            } else {
                return '';
            }
        }

        function rfc3986_decode($raw_input) {
            return rawurldecode($raw_input);
        }

    }

    class GmailGetContacts {

        function get_request_token($oauth, $usePost=false, $useHmacSha1Sig=true, $passOAuthInHeader=false) {
            $retarr = array();  // return value
            $response = array();

            $url = 'https://www.google.com/accounts/OAuthGetRequestToken';
            $params['oauth_version'] = '1.0';
            $params['oauth_nonce'] = mt_rand();
            $params['oauth_timestamp'] = time();
            $params['oauth_consumer_key'] = $oauth->oauth_consumer_key;
            $params['oauth_callback'] = $oauth->callback;
            $params['scope'] = 'https://www.google.com/m8/feeds';

            // compute signature and add it to the params list
            if ($useHmacSha1Sig) {

                $params['oauth_signature_method'] = 'HMAC-SHA1';
                $params['oauth_signature'] =
                        $oauth->oauth_compute_hmac_sig($usePost ? 'POST' : 'GET', $url, $params,
                                $oauth->oauth_consumer_secret, null);
            } else {
                echo "signature mathod not support";
            }

            // Pass OAuth credentials in a separate header or in the query string
            if ($passOAuthInHeader) {

                $query_parameter_string = $oauth->oauth_http_build_query($params, FALSE);

                $header = $oauth->build_oauth_header($params);

                $headers[] = $header;
            } else {
                $query_parameter_string = $oauth->oauth_http_build_query($params);
            }

            // POST or GET the request
            if ($usePost) {
                $request_url = $url;
                $oauth->logit("getreqtok:INFO:request_url:$request_url");
                $oauth->logit("getreqtok:INFO:post_body:$query_parameter_string");
                $headers[] = 'Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded';
                $response = do_post($request_url, $query_parameter_string, 443, $headers);
            } else {
                $request_url = $url . ($query_parameter_string ?
                                ('?' . $query_parameter_string) : '' );

                $oauth->logit("getreqtok:INFO:request_url:$request_url");

                $response = $oauth->do_get($request_url, 443, $headers);
            }

            // extract successful response
            if (!empty($response)) {
                list($info, $header, $body) = $response;
                $body_parsed = $oauth->oauth_parse_str($body);
                if (!empty($body_parsed)) {
                    $oauth->logit("getreqtok:INFO:response_body_parsed:");
                   //print_r($body_parsed);
                }
                $retarr = $response;
                $retarr[] = $body_parsed;
            }

            return $body_parsed;
        }

        function get_access_token($oauth, $request_token, $request_token_secret, $oauth_verifier, $usePost=false, $useHmacSha1Sig=true, $passOAuthInHeader=true) {
            $retarr = array();  // return value
            $response = array();

            $url = 'https://www.google.com/accounts/OAuthGetAccessToken';
            $params['oauth_version'] = '1.0';
            $params['oauth_nonce'] = mt_rand();
            $params['oauth_timestamp'] = time();
            $params['oauth_consumer_key'] = $oauth->oauth_consumer_key;
            $params['oauth_token'] = $request_token;
            $params['oauth_verifier'] = $oauth_verifier;

            // compute signature and add it to the params list
            if ($useHmacSha1Sig){
                $params['oauth_signature_method'] = 'HMAC-SHA1';
                $params['oauth_signature'] =
                        $oauth->oauth_compute_hmac_sig($usePost ? 'POST' : 'GET', $url, $params,
                                $oauth->oauth_consumer_secret, $request_token_secret);
            } else {
                echo "signature mathod not support";
            }
    //     
            if ($passOAuthInHeader) {
                $query_parameter_string = $oauth->oauth_http_build_query($params, false);
                $header = $oauth->build_oauth_header($params);
                $headers[] = $header;
            } else {
                $query_parameter_string = $oauth->oauth_http_build_query($params);
            }


            if ($usePost){
                $request_url = $url;
                logit("getacctok:INFO:request_url:$request_url");
                logit("getacctok:INFO:post_body:$query_parameter_string");
                $headers[] = 'Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded';
                $response = $oauth->do_post($request_url, $query_parameter_string, 443, $headers);
            } else {
                $request_url = $url . ($query_parameter_string ?
                                ('?' . $query_parameter_string) : '' );

                $oauth->logit("getacctok:INFO:request_url:$request_url");
                $response = $oauth->do_get($request_url, 443, $headers);
            }


            if (!empty($response)) {
                list($info, $header, $body) = $response;
                $body_parsed = $oauth->oauth_parse_str($body);
                if (!empty($body_parsed)) {
                    $oauth->logit("getacctok:INFO:response_body_parsed:");
                    //print_r($body_parsed);

                }
                $retarr = $response;
                $retarr[] = $body_parsed;
            }
            return $body_parsed;
        }


        function GetContacts($oauth, $access_token, $access_token_secret, $usePost=false, $passOAuthInHeader=true,$emails_count) {
            $retarr = array();  // return value
            $response = array();

            $url = "https://www.google.com/m8/feeds/contacts/default/full";
            $params['alt'] = 'json';
            $params['max-results'] = $emails_count;
            $params['oauth_version'] = '1.0';
            $params['oauth_nonce'] = mt_rand();
            $params['oauth_timestamp'] = time();
            $params['oauth_consumer_key'] = $oauth->oauth_consumer_key;
            $params['oauth_token'] = $access_token;

            // compute hmac-sha1 signature and add it to the params list
            $params['oauth_signature_method'] = 'HMAC-SHA1';
            $params['oauth_signature'] =
                    $oauth->oauth_compute_hmac_sig($usePost ? 'POST' : 'GET', $url, $params,
                            $oauth->oauth_consumer_secret, $access_token_secret);

            // Pass OAuth credentials in a separate header or in the query string
            if ($passOAuthInHeader){
                $query_parameter_string = $oauth->oauth_http_build_query($params, false);

                $header = $oauth->build_oauth_header($params);

                $headers[] = $header;
            } else {
                $query_parameter_string = $oauth->oauth_http_build_query($params);
            }

            // POST or GET the request
            if ($usePost){
                $request_url = $url;
                $oauth->logit("callcontact:INFO:request_url:$request_url");
                $oauth->logit("callcontact:INFO:post_body:$query_parameter_string");
                $headers[] = 'Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded';
                $response = $oauth->do_post($request_url, $query_parameter_string, 80, $headers);

            } else {
                $request_url = $url . ($query_parameter_string ?
                                ('?' . $query_parameter_string) : '' );
                $oauth->logit("callcontact:INFO:request_url:$request_url");
                $response = $oauth->do_get($request_url, 443, $headers);
            }


            if (!empty($response)) {
                list($info, $header, $body) = $response;
                if ($body) {

                    $oauth->logit("callcontact:INFO:response:");
                    $contact = json_decode($oauth->json_pretty_print($body), true);

                   //echo $contact['feed']['entry'][0]['gd$email'][0]['address'];
                   return $contact['feed']['entry'];

                }
                $retarr = $response;
            }

            return $retarr;
        }

    }

    ?>
```

Can you guys help me on this one please. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure if this can help you as you say you have already used print_r *(are you using with braces?)*, but to display the contents of an array in PHP, I have always used this with success.
It displays the integer ref of the array plus the data in each field.

```
<?php
  echo "<pre>";                //print array to console
    {print_r($variable_name);}
  echo "</pre>";
?>
```

Alternately, have you checked the information here: https://developers.google.com/google-apps/contacts/v3/#retrieving_contacts_using_query_parameters

Or try the Context.IO API - there's a call specifically for pulling contacts: http://context.io/docs/2.0/accounts/contacts

Hoping any of these might help you.

Comment: i used what u told me and got something like this:

    Array
    (
    [rel] => http://schemas.google.com/g/2005#other
    [address] => miguelmora@canal15.com.ni
    [primary] => true
    )
    Array
    (
    [deleted] => false
    [href] => http://www.google.com/m8/feeds/groups/elvistillalive%40gmail.com/base/6f15aa1a8fe4768a
    )
    Array
    (
    [rel] => http://schemas.google.com/g/2005#mobile
    [$t] => 867-970-98
    )

Comment: i can see the mobile in [$t}=> 867-970-98, but how do i get it into a variable.

Answer (score 0):

For your case for first Phone andress and Note Field .

add where you loop the contacts in gmail.php

```
foreach($contacts as $k => $a)
{
  $phone1 = end($a['gd$phoneNumber'][0]);
  $note = end($a['content']);
  $adress = end($a['gd$postalAddress'][0]);
```